# How to make this iteration loop between all columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe called `df`  which has the following columns header of data:

| bureau0 | bureau1 | bureau2 | bureau3 | bureau4 | waysConstitution |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4753900 | 4773300 | NaN | 4713002 | Three | 2135 |
| 4721103 | NaN | NaN | NaN | 4751201 | 2135 |
| 6204000 | 6201501 | 6319400 | NaN | 6201501 | 2062 |
| 7911200 | 8230001 | NaN | 8291100 | NaN | 2135 |
| 4713002 | NaN | NaN | 4751201 | 4753900 | 2054 |

In fact, the bureau column goes up to 100, but I think these 5 cols examples already help.

I also have another dataset, called top_bureau, which contains some bureau code. Like this:

| top_bureau |
| --- |
| 7911200 |
| 4713002 |
| 4773300 |
| 5811500 |
| 6201501 |

A more lines in the top_bureau, but I think for example it should work.

**What I would like to do is:** Create a new column in df that returns the value "potential_costumer" if in any bureau column there is some code that has in top_bureau and the waysConstitution column has the value equal to "2135" or "2062".

**Expected output:**

| bureau0 | bureau1 | bureau2 | bureau3 | bureau4 | waysConstitution | potential_customer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4753900 | 4773300 | NaN | 4713002 | Three | 2135 | Yes |
| 4721103 | NaN | NaN | NaN | 4751201 | 2135 | Yes |
| 6204000 | 6201501 | 6319400 | NaN | 6201501 | 2062 | Yes |
| 7911200 | 8230001 | NaN | 8291100 | NaN | 2135 | Yes |
| 4713002 | NaN | NaN | 4751201 | 4753900 | 2054 | No |

**Reasoning example:**
As in line 1, in the bureau3 column the value "4713002" is in the top_bureau table and the "waysConstitution" column is equal to 2135 or 2062 so this customer can be flagged as a potential customer

How to make this iteration loop between all columns?

Comment: I added an example of output and the rational for the calculation

Comment: your second True seems incorrect, no value is in top_bureau

Comment: Also, for the fourth column(bureau4) ,  it is not advisable to have mixed datatypes when comparing numbers..!! You might want to check that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can perform simple boolean indexing.

I am assuming `df` the first dataframe and `df2` the second one.

```
# is any row value in top_bureau?
m1 = df.filter(like='bureau').isin(df2['top_bureau'].unique()).any(1)
# is waysConstitution 2135 or 2062?
m2 = df['waysConstitution'].isin([2135, 2062])

# if both conditions are True, add a "potential_customer" string
df.loc[m1&m2, 'new'] = 'potential_customer'
```

output:

```
   bureau0    bureau1    bureau2    bureau3  bureau4  waysConstitution                 new
0  4753900  4773300.0        NaN  4713002.0    Three              2135  potential_customer
1  4721103        NaN        NaN        NaN  4751201              2135                 NaN
2  6204000  6201501.0  6319400.0        NaN  6201501              2062  potential_customer
3  7911200  8230001.0        NaN  8291100.0      NaN              2135  potential_customer
4  4713002        NaN        NaN  4751201.0  4753900              2054                 NaN
```

###### alternative output (Yes/No):

```
import numpy as np
m1 = df.filter(like='bureau').isin(df2['top_bureau'].unique()).any(1)
m2 = df['waysConstitution'].isin([2135, 2062])

df['potential_customer'] = np.where(m1&m2, 'Yes', 'No')
```

output:

```
   bureau0    bureau1    bureau2    bureau3  bureau4  waysConstitution potential_customer
0  4753900  4773300.0        NaN  4713002.0    Three              2135                Yes
1  4721103        NaN        NaN        NaN  4751201              2135                 No
2  6204000  6201501.0  6319400.0        NaN  6201501              2062                Yes
3  7911200  8230001.0        NaN  8291100.0      NaN              2135                Yes
4  4713002        NaN        NaN  4751201.0  4753900              2054                 No
```

Comment: What if instead of Yes or No, I wanted to put how many top_bureau appears on that row?

Comment: @Marjorie do you mean how many matches if several?

Comment: `df['potential_customer'] = df.filter(like='bureau').isin(df2['top_bureau'].unique()).sum(1)`?

Comment: Yes, for example in line 1 there are 3 bureau that appear in the table of top_bureau

Comment: Yes but only 2 match in top_bureau

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways to do it, as you can see by the solutions. Here's another:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

top_bureau = ['7911200','4713002','4773300','5811500','6201501']

columns = ['bureau0','bureau1','bureau2','bureau3','bureau4','waysConstitution']
data = [['4753900', '4773300',  np.nan, '4713002',  'Three',    '2135'],
['4721103', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, '4751201',  '2135'],
['6204000', '6201501',  '6319400',  np.nan, '6201501',  '2062'],
['7911200', '8230001',  np.nan, '8291100',  np.nan, '2135'],
['123', np.nan, np.nan, '456',  '789',  '101112'],
['4713002', np.nan, np.nan, '4751201',  '4753900',  '2054']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)


df['check'] = df[df.columns].apply(lambda x: list(x), axis=1)
potentialCustomerIdx = list(df[(pd.DataFrame(df.check.tolist()).isin(top_bureau).any(1).values) & (df['waysConstitution'].isin(["2135","2062"]))].index)

df['potential_customer'] = 'No'
df.loc[potentialCustomerIdx,'potential_customer'] = 'Yes'
df = df.drop(['check'],axis=1)
```

**Output:**

```
print(df)
   bureau0  bureau1  bureau2  ...  bureau4 waysConstitution potential_customer
0  4753900  4773300      NaN  ...    Three             2135                Yes
1  4721103      NaN      NaN  ...  4751201             2135                 No
2  6204000  6201501  6319400  ...  6201501             2062                Yes
3  7911200  8230001      NaN  ...      NaN             2135                Yes
4      123      NaN      NaN  ...      789           101112                 No
5  4713002      NaN      NaN  ...  4753900             2054                 No

[6 rows x 7 columns]
```